# Unable to install packages on macos

Tags: r

When I try to install a package in R on macOS I get the following error, both using the GUI menu or `install.packages`:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.uni-muenster.de/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.uni-muenster.de/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
```

There are many Q&A on this site relating to this issue, and none of the answers provided there worked for me.

I tried disabling my firewall, changed all possible settings in the R preferences, checked in my browser whether the packet was online and available (it was), used different options and mirrors, both http and https, in `install_packages`, to no avail.

Comment: What version of R do you have?

Comment: Sorry, I can't find "the following error" in your question.

Comment: Try a different CRAN mirror?

Comment: @Roland I did. See my answer. I'm providing this in the hope that it will help someone else, as Little Snitch is a widespread network monitor on macOS and none of the other Q&A thought of this possible source of the problem.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Little Snitch, check the rules.

I use Little Snitch in quiet mode and have never defined any rules, and yet **Little Snitch had a rule that blocked R from accessing the internet**. Maybe Little Snitch installs with a certain set of base rules or creates rules for certain types of software by default. My bit torrent client (qbittorrent) and Cisco's VPN client, which I use to access my university network from home, were both blocked out of the box as well.

I deleted that rule and now packet installation works fine.